# Python file runs using python command but not using Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I have a small application built using Flask and  [Flask-restx](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I can run the app using `python app.py` and the flask server runs on port 8888. I try to run the file using `set FLASK_APP=app.py` and run using `flask run` which seems to run, but doesnt open my swagger page. Please advice.

app.py

```
import logging.config

import os
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_cors import CORS
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
from src.config import default
from src.api.controllers.endpoints.users import ns as users_namespace
from src.api.controllers.endpoints.statuses import ns as status_namespace
from src.api import api
from src.database import db

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
logging_conf_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../logging.conf'))
logging.config.fileConfig(logging_conf_path)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def configure_app(flask_app):
    flask_app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = default.FLASK_SERVER_NAME
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = default.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = default.SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS
    flask_app.config['SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION'] = default.RESTPLUS_SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_VALIDATE'] = default.RESTPLUS_VALIDATE
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER'] = default.RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER
    flask_app.config['ERROR_404_HELP'] = default.RESTPLUS_ERROR_404_HELP


def initialize_app(flask_app):
    configure_app(flask_app)

    blueprint = Blueprint('CovidAPI', __name__, url_prefix='/')
    api.init_app(blueprint)
    api.add_namespace(users_namespace)
    api.add_namespace(status_namespace)
    flask_app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

    db.init_app(flask_app)


def main():
    initialize_app(app)
    log.info('>>>>> Starting development server at http://{}/ <<<<<'.format(app.config['SERVER_NAME']))
    app.run(debug=default.FLASK_DEBUG)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Flask Settings:

```
# Flask settings
FLASK_SERVER_NAME = 'localhost:8888'
FLASK_DEBUG = True  # Do not use debug mode in production

# Flask-Restplus settings
RESTPLUS_SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION = 'list'
RESTPLUS_VALIDATE = True
RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER = False
RESTPLUS_ERROR_404_HELP = False
```

Output using python command:

```
2020-04-29 10:25:42,519 - __main__ - INFO - >>>>> Starting development server at http://localhost:8888/ <<<<<
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
2020-04-29 10:25:42,610 - werkzeug - INFO -  * Restarting with stat
2020-04-29 10:25:45,398 - __main__ - INFO - >>>>> Starting development server at http://localhost:8888/ <<<<<
2020-04-29 10:25:45,426 - werkzeug - WARNING -  * Debugger is active!
2020-04-29 10:25:45,458 - werkzeug - INFO -  * Debugger PIN: 258-749-652
2020-04-29 10:25:45,530 - werkzeug - INFO -  * Running on http://localhost:8888/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Running through flask run:

```
 * Serving Flask app "src\app.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 313-115-045
 * Running on http://localhost:6000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flask run` command works by importing an `app` object from your `app.py` module.

Therefor the stuff in this function is never executed in that case:

```
def main():
    initialize_app(app)
    log.info('>>>>> Starting development server at http://{}/ <<<<<'.format(app.config['SERVER_NAME']))
    app.run(debug=default.FLASK_DEBUG)
```

When running with the `python app.py` command it is, because this gets executed:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm not sure how it runs fully in your case with `python`, as neither the `configure_app` or `initialize_app` functions return the app object.  However, you may wish to change the code to something like:

```
# ...

def configure_app(flask_app):
    # ...
    return flask_app

def initialize_app(flask_app):
    # ...
    return flask_app

app = initialize_app(app)
```

Now that (fully configured) `app` object is avaialable to `flask run`. You shouldn't need to set the `FLASK_ENV` environment variable, as it looks for an object called `app` by default.

If you still want the ability to run with the interpreter, then add this block to the end, although this is kinda defunct if using the `flask` command.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log.info('>>>>> Starting development server at http://{}/ <<<<<'.format(app.config['SERVER_NAME']))
    app.run(debug=default.FLASK_DEBUG)
```